# Group result by 15 minutes time interval in MongoDb Using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I would like to convert MYSQL Query to MongoDB PHP Query I have tried it but not working.

```
SELECT time,ch1,ch2,ch3,ch4,ch5,ch6,ch7,ch8 FROM logs WHERE date_time >= '2021-07-05T12:12:48.000Z' AND date_time<= '2021-07-05T13:12:48.000Z' GROUP BY date_time(25m) fill(0) tz('Asia/Kolkata')
```

I have converted in mongo PHP but getting errors.

```
     $results = $this->dbs->$collection_name->aggregate(array(
            array(      
                '$match' => array(
                    'date_time' => array
                    (
                        '$gte' => $from_date, '$lte' => $to_date
                    )
                )
            ),
            array(
                '$group' => array(
                   '_id' => array(
                        '$toDate' => array(
                            '$subtract' => array(
                                array('$toLong'=> array('$toDate'=> '$_id')),
                                array('$mod'=> array('$toLong'=> array('$toDate'=> '$_id'),1000 * 60 * 15) )
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                )
            )
        ));
```

> error : this error  come :  Fatal error: Uncaught
> MongoDB\Driver\Exception\CommandException: An object representing an
> expression must have exactly one field: { $toLong: { $toDate: "$_id"
> }, 0: 900000 } in
> F:\xamp\htdocs\logger\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\Operation\Aggregate.php:298
> Stack trace: #0
> F:\xamp\htdocs\logger\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\Operation\Aggregate.php(298):
> MongoDB\Driver\Server->executeReadCommand('clients_logers',
> Object(MongoDB\Driver\Command), Array) #1
> F:\xamp\htdocs\logger\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\Collection.php(258):
> MongoDB\Operation\Aggregate->execute(Object(MongoDB\Driver\Server)) #

Comment: Please add the details of the error you are getting so as it becomes easy to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation pipeline to do following:

1. convert the `datetime` field to timestamp(by `$subtract` 1970-01-01)
2. perform integer division on the timestamp field by 15 minute = 15 * 60 * 1000 = 900000 ms
3. multiply the result back by 900000ms
4. convert back to `datetime`(by '$add' 1970-01-01)
5. group by the 15minute-group result

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eLEAhgHScOk) for your reference.

Comment: can you give example using the PHP library?